# Convert C++ to VB.Net issues

Tags: c++, vb.net

I've got few issues, I want to convert a small snippet from c++ to vb.net but I can't do it really since I've got no clue what std:: is in vb.net

```
inline float NormalizeAngle(float flAng)
{
    if(!std::isfinite(flAng))
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    return std::remainder(flAng, 360.0f);
}
```

And this

```
inline void ClampViewAngles(Vector3_t& vecAng)
{
    vecAng.x = std::max(-89.0f, std::min(89.0f, NormalizeAngle(vecAng.x)));
    vecAng.y = NormalizeAngle(vecAng.y);
    vecAng.z = 0.0f;
}
```

Apprently it's (isNan in vb.net I'm not sure.) Google didn't help me out!

Comment: You can lookup these functions and what they do in the [c++ reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite). I think what `std::max()` is should be pretty obious.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   std::max is getting the largest number, std::min the smallest number. But I've got no clue on how to do this in vb.net couldn't find any equivalent.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I found Math.Max and Math.Min is that the correct equivalent for std::max and min?

Comment: You may not find equivalents for all functions from the c++ standard libraries in vb.net, so be prepared you may need to roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test on Double.IsInfinity or Double.IsNan
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

To have Min and Max method, you need to Imports System.Math at top of your vb file and you will get all the other goodies for arithmetic
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, std::remainder translates to System.Math.IEEERemainder.